# Wordpress Doesn't Generate Taxonomy Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I have a post type named 'publication' and a taxonomy named 'area'. For some reason, I cannot seem to get Wordpress to generate a taxonomy archive for the terms of 'area' from my custom taxonomy.php template or any variable [taxonomy templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png). Wordpress will always choose to use archive.php to generate the archive for the Area taxonomy.

I assume I'm missing something simple. Here's how my post type and taxonomy are registered in functions.php:

**Publication post type**

```
    function publication_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x("Publications", "Publications"),
        'singular_name' => _x("Publication", "Publication"),
        'menu_name' => 'Publications',
        'add_new' => _x("Add New", "publication item"),
        'add_new_item' => __("Add New Publication"),
        'edit_item' => __("Edit Publication"),
        'new_item' => __("New Publication"),
        'view_item' => __("View Publication"),
        'search_items' => __("Search Publications"),
        'not_found' =>  __("No Publications Found"),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __("No Publications Found in Trash"),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    register_post_type('publication' , array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-text',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'publication_post_type', 0 );
```

**Area taxonomy**

```
    function publications_taxonomy() {

    $singular = 'Area';
    $plural = 'Areas';
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( $plural, "areas"),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singular, "area"),
        'search_items' =>  __("Search $singular"),
        'all_items' => __("All $singular"),
        'parent_item' => __("Parent $singular"),
        'parent_item_colon' => __("Parent $singular:"),
        'edit_item' => __("Edit $singular"),
        'update_item' => __("Update $singular"),
        'add_new_item' => __("Add New $singular"),
        'new_item_name' => __("New $singular Name"),
    );

    register_taxonomy( strtolower($singular), array( 'publication' ), array(
        'public' => true,

        'capabilities' => array(
            'manage_terms'=> 'manage_categories',
            'edit_terms'=> 'manage_categories',
            'delete_terms'=> 'manage_categories',
            'assign_terms' => 'read'
        ),

        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'labels' => $labels
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'publications_taxonomy', 0 );
```

I have read through the Wordpress documentation and various answers related to taxonomy.php and the template hierarchy on Stack Exchange, but to no avail. Any idea what's going on here?